# includepdf in pdflscape environment

Tags: graphics, pdfpages, pdflscape

I want to include a pdf containing a scalable vector graphic in my document. Because of the graphic's width it must be imported in landscape mode (which works). However, I want to rotate the whole page as well (so that the reader does not need to turn the page manually.

I tried something like:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

...

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includepdf[landscape=true,pages=1]{figures/diagram.pdf}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

which rotates the graphic but not the page itself. When I comment out the `\includepdf` line, the page would be rotated as well.

Is there a way to rotate both the graphic and the page?

Comment: you can do all this with pdfpages see the doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `\includegraphics` itself?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[page=10,angle=-90,width=\linewidth]{pgfmanual.pdf}
    \end{figure}
  \end{landscape}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why I haven't tried that before :-D Since I'm too low on reputation, here you have a personal: +1