# How to change from Landscape to Portrait for the rest of the document

Tags: landscape

I'd searched a while for changing the orientation of my LaTeX document from landscape to portrait in a way, that I can include other pdfs with `\includepdf[..]{..}` without messing around with my document layout.

The minimal example of my document looks like this. Because of many includes of other tex files it is hard to give a more complex example, at the content of my document class and other options and package-imports are provided (If necessary, you can view the whole code [here](https://github.com/chordbook)).

### Class file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{chordbook}
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{scrartcl}


\RequirePackage[chorded]{songs}
\RequirePackage{caption}

\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage{longtable}

% Header
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[OL,ER]{\textbf{\myauthor's Chordbook 2015}\\}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf{Seite \thepage} \\ \textit{\leftmark}}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-17.4mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-22.4mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{15mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{173mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{280mm}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}

\setlength{\songnumwidth}{15mm}
\setlength{\versenumwidth}{10mm}

\renewcommand\printchord[1]{\sffamily\slshape\small#1}

\newcommand\chordbrk{\hspace*{6.2mm}}

\RequirePackage[final]{pdfpages}
\cfoot{}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
```

### Document

```
\documentclass[landscape]{../TeX/chordbook}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[%
    colorlinks=true,
    pdfstartview=FitV,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=green,
    urlcolor=red,
    %debug=true,
    hyperfigures=true%
    ]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\songcolumns{2}
\columnsep=3mm

\renewcommand{\snumbgcolor}{songnr}
\renewcommand{\notebgcolor}{notes}
\renewcommand\printchord[1]{\footnotesize\sffamily
    \textit{\textcolor{linkcolor}{{#1}}}}

    \clearpage
    \songsection{A Capella}
        \begin{songs}{}
            ...
        \end{songs}

    \clearpage
    \songsection{Classic}
        \begin{songs}{}
            ...
        \end{songs}

    \clearpage
    \songsection{Folk and Medieval}
        \begin{songs}{}
            ...
        \end{songs}

    \clearpage
    \songsection{Fun}
        \begin{songs}{}
            ...
        \end{songs}{}

    \clearpage
    \songsection{Modern / Rock}{}
        \begin{songs}{}
            ...
        \end{songs}

    \clearpage
    \songsection{Oldies}
        \begin{songs}{}
            ...
        \end{songs}

    \clearpage
    \songsection{Other}
        \begin{songs}{}
            ...
        \end{songs}


    \begin{appendix}
        \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}
        %\setlength{\hoffset}{-17.4mm}
        %\setlength{\voffset}{-22.4mm}
        %\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
        %\setlength{\headheight}{15mm}
        %\setlength{\headsep}{5mm}
        %\setlength{\textheight}{173mm}
        %\setlength{\textwidth}{280mm}
        %\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
        \setlength{\marginparsep}{-30mm}
        \setlength{\marginparwidth}{-30mm}
        %\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}
        \begin{landscape}
            \includepdf[pages=-,scale=0.9,landscape]{../src/appendix/i_see_fire.pdf}
        \end{landscape}
    \end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

So my problem now is, that the included pdf will start about 40mm off the left margin but I am not able to reduce this length; also negativ values for

- \hoffset
- \oddsidemargin
- \marginparsep
- \parginparwidth

did not work, actually altering their values did not change anything.

I provide a [link](https://download.niederhoelle.org/error-1.png) to a screenshot here, because I have not enough reputation to upload screenshots directly.

Does somebody have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

I cannot find a switch-like command or something like `portrait` ...

Regards
hringriin

Comment: Why not use: `\usepackage{pdflscape} \begin{landscape}
...
\end{landscape}`?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240928/includepdf-in-pdflscape-environment and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111404/pdflscape-and-tikzpagenodes-problem

Comment: @AboAmmar, I am already using it. It does not look good, because the left margin is too big and there's actually no right margin (see my screenshot here again: https://download.niederhoelle.org/error-1.png)

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thank you, the first link helped. The solution for me was to swap to `\includegraphics` and abandon `\includepdf`. I was not aware of the possibility to include pdfs with graphicx, too.

Answer (score 2):

The full solution is this:

```
<<<<<

\begin{landscape}
    \includepdf[pages=-,scale=0.9,landscape]{../src/appendix/i_see_fire.pdf}
\end{landscape}

=====

\setlength{\textheight}{195mm}
\begin{landscape}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.93]{../src/appendix/i_see_fire.pdf}
\end{landscape}

>>>>>
```

With `\includepdf` there is no change when altering the values vor `\textheight` by the way.

Regards
hringriin